# Google Reward Video Ad Skip Button Closing ViewController

Tags: swift, admob, adsense, admob-rewardedvideoad

I use GADRewardBasedVideoAd. If I watch the video to the end it works fine, but when I press the skip video button after 5 sec. The Video ad is being dismissed, but so is the view that presented the add. Any help would be appreciated. I do nothing special, I just present the add like this:

```
func rewardBasedVideoAdDidReceive(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
    print(rewardBasedVideoAd)
    if GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().isReady == true {
        GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().present(fromRootViewController: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it on device? Same happened to me until I tried on a device. I think is something wrong on the emulator...

Comment: The issue occurs when I use it on my device - very strange, is your code the same as mine?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Same is happening on device. Yes, basically is the same code. Anybody?